# Push data from Ion input to another page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am struggling with Routing data from ion input to another page. I am trying to push the phone number from page 1, phonenumber, to page 2, mobile-verify, the number in phonenumbers html page consists of two inputs country code and the number itself. I added mobileverify/:myid/:another to the path in the app-routing.module.ts. I am currently getting a No provider for NavController!

Here is my code

phonenumber.html

```
                    <ion-row>  
                  <ion-col>
                      <ion-item (click)="openSelect()">
                    <div class="ion-text-left">

                        <ion-label>Country</ion-label>
                        <ion-input [(ngModel)]="selectedCode"></ion-input>
                      </div>
                    </ion-item>
                        <ion-item style="display: none">
                            <div class="ion-text-left">
                                <ion-label >Country</ion-label>
                                <ion-select #select1 [(ngModel)]="selectedCode">
                                    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let c of countries" value="{{c.flag}}{{c.code}}">{{c.flag}}{{c.name}}</ion-select-option>
                                  </ion-select>

                              </div>
            </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
              <ion-col>
                <ion-item>
              <div class="ion-text-right">
                  <ion-label>Phone Number</ion-label> 

                  <ion-input #user2 type="tel" maxlength="14" minlength="4" [(ngModel)]="numpad" 
                  name="userCount" (keypress)="numberOnlyValidation($event)"></ion-input>

                </div>
              </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
  </ion-row>



        <ion-button 
         expand="full" 
         color= {{ButtonColor}}
         size="large"
         [routerLink]="['/mobile-verify']"
         [disabled]="!numpad && !selectedCode"
         (click)="pushPage()"
        >
         Register
        </ion-button>
```

phonenumber.ts

```
     @ViewChild('select1', {static: false}) select1: Select;
     countries: any = [
        {
          code: '+93',
          name: 'Afghanistan',
        },

        {
          code: '+263',
          name: 'Zimbabwe',
        },
      ];

     openSelect() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.select1.open();
        }, 150);
      }
      numberOnlyValidation(event: any) {
        const pattern = /[0-9]/;
        let inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);

        if (!pattern.test(inputChar)) {
          // invalid character, prevent input
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      }
      constructor(private nav: NavController) { }


    pushPage() {
      this.nav.goForward(`/mobile-verify/${this.select1}${this.inputChar}`);
      }
    }
```

mobile-verify.html

```
    <div class="secondcenter">
                    <p text-center>We have sent it to {{number}}</p>
                  </div>
```

mobile-verify.ts

```
      import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
    //import { selectedCode, numpad } from './src/app/phonenumber';
    //import { router } from '@angular/router'

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-mobile-verify',
      templateUrl: './mobile-verify.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./mobile-verify.page.scss'],
    })
    export class MobileVerifyPage implements OnInit {

      number = null;
      constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.number = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('myid, another');
      }
```

[image: What I want my number to look like in the mobile-verify page]

Comment: You have to import `NavController`to use it: `import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';`

Comment: If this does not solve the error please make a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) out of the code so your code is easier to understand and debug.

Comment: I have imported it to the phone number page. Do I need to also import it to the mobile-veirfy page?